# Myhill-Nerode theorem matrix to automata

Tags: c++, automata, dfa

I've successfully implemented the Myhill-Nerode theorem in C++. When it finishes to minimize a given automata a matrix is given as an answer.

Using the automata on this page: http://web.stcloudstate.edu/pkjha/CSCI502/Minimize.html, I have the final matrix (which is the complete matrix of the given matrix, not the lower triangular):

```
- x x x x x x x x 
x - - x x x x x x 
x - - x x x x x x 
x x x - - - - x x 
x x x - - - - x x 
x x x - - - - x x 
x x x - - - - x x 
x x x x x x x - - 
x x x x x x x - -
```

which means that lines: 1,2,4 and 8 are all different states, and lines (1), (2,3), (4,5,6,7) and (8,9) can be grouped into the same state.

I'm using a class to represent each of the states of the automata according to this structure:

```
class state{
    public:
        string state_name;        
        vector<string> transitions; 
        bool final;                
        bool start;            
    public:
        state(string,vector<string>,bool,bool);
};
```

in which, state name is the name of my current state (A,B,C,D,state1,...), transitions is a string vector containing the name of each state that my automata can go, final is a boolean indicating if my state is an accepting state and start is a boolean indicating if my state is a start state.

For example, for node q0 of the given automata, its structure would be something like:

```
state_name: q0
transitions: (q1,q2) <- always following the alphabet order
final: false
start: true
```

My problem is: I need to convert this matrix into an automata structure following the structure given. I can easily identify starting/final states, since I have the original automata information, and I can easily identify each of the groups.

What I can't figure out in the matrix are the transitions between the groups. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each state is a member of some group, and for each group you have a list of the states in the group.  To find the transitions for a group G1, pick one of the states S1 in the group, take the transitions for S1, and for each target state S2 find the corresponding group G2.  The set of all the G2 you obtain make up the transitions from G1.  (Note that because all the states in G1 are equivalent, you only need to consider one representative state S1.)

Comment: So, first I'll create all the groups, then I'll take one of the states that belongs to this group and check its transitions and those transitions will be the transitions for the whole group?

Comment: Yes.  Note that if a state has transitions to two different states which turned out to be equivalent, then those two states will be in the same group.  So if you just make a list of the groups corresponding to the target states, you could get duplicate groups in the list.